# Access portlet namespace in Freemarker template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I'm using a freemarker template to display web contents listed in an asset publisher.

In the template I'm trying to assign the portlet-namespace in order to use some asset features (like printing the entry) like this

```
<#attempt>
  <#assign namespace = request["portlet-namespace"]>
  <#recover>
  <#assign namespace = 'undefined'>
</#attempt>
```

So, the print button is holding te code below

```
<a href="javascript:${namespace}printPage_0();" title='Print'>
```

`printPage` is the method used in liferay asset publisher code in `asset_print.jspf`

Well, everything is working fine: when inspecting the page in a browser, I verified that the namespace has been calculated and assigned to namespace variable as well (and no error displayed in UI). However, liferay portal logs the following each time a user tries to see the whole web content (ie. clicks on read more) from the asset publisher

```
Expression request["portlet-namespace"] is undefined on line
```

Anyone has seen this problem ? Is there another way to get the portlet-namespace in a freemarker template ?

Answer (score 1):

`#attempt`/`#recover` is not for recovering from normal situations, and by default it logs the error when it recovers (so that the operators will be alerted). You should instead use the `exp!default` operator:

```
<#assign namespace = request["portlet-namespace"]!'undefined'>
```

(Though I'm not sure why printing `undefinedprintPage_0();` makes sense, but that's a different issue.)